# Google Developers Console - Error when inviting user to project

Tags: console, cloud, project

I have a new project in the developers console, and cannot seem to add new users. I send the invitation, this is forwarded to the correct Gmail account with the RSVP link:

'https://console.developers.google.com/project/[appname]/rsvp/'

which however results in an error message:

'The server has encountered a problem. Please try again.'

We tried inviting other gmail users and still no luck.

We also made this user an administrator of the billing account, and that works fine. Just the project is not visible to the user.

Anyone has an idea what could be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was in the automatic link sent by Google, which read:

https://console.developers.google.com/project/app[projectname]/rsvp/

but should have been

https://console.developers.google.com/project/app%7E[projectname]/rsvp/

It seems somewhere on the way the tilde got lost.

After changing the link by hand the RSVP works fine.

I hope this helps someone else in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same Problem, i realised that i was logged in to several google accounts, work, private etc...

I logged out and logged back in with the account i was invited to the console project and hit the link sent in the email, surprisingly it worked.

Good luck, for anyone else encountering this problem.